# Problems with Android Manifest file

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Here is the Code, I keep getting errors with what I believe is syntax, but I'm not able to fix, I'm new to android development and I need to complete this project by next week, if there's a resource someone could direct me towards to help solve this problem that would be great!
(android studio specifically is telling me multiple root tags, tag name expected,tag start was not closed, and unexpected end of file)

EDIT: sorry about formatting I think I fixed it
EDIT2: I've narrowed it down to just one multiple root tag, still unsure of how to solve problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="shake.shake"/>

<application
android:allowBackup="true" 
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" 
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true" 
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity
    android:name=".MainPage">
    <intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
            />
        <category
            android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="shake.shake.ShakePage" 
    android:label="@string/title_activity_shake_page"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" 
    android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme"
    android:parentActivityName="shake.shake.MainPage">
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" 
    android:value="shake.shake.MainPage" />
</activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have excluded `<application>` from `<manifest>` tag.
The `<application>` must reside within `<manifest>` tag (parent).

```
<manifest>
    <application>
       ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I deleted my answer as yours was more succinct.

Answer (score 0):

```
< Original<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

It seems to me that this line has no end tag to be found throughout the codes that you provide up there.. hehe.. not sure whether it is this ;)

Comment: heh, yeah I fixed that once I realized how funky the formatting was

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="shake.shake">

<application
android:allowBackup="true" 
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" 
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true" 
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity
    android:name=".MainPage">
    <intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
            />
        <category
            android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="shake.shake.ShakePage" 
    android:label="@string/title_activity_shake_page"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" 
    android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme"
    android:parentActivityName="shake.shake.MainPage">
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" 
    android:value="shake.shake.MainPage" />
</activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

How about trying this

Answer (score 0):

Just try to get the meta-data tag out from here and put it under the closing activity tag and see. For instance;

```
   <activity
     android:name="shake.shake.ShakePage" 
     android:label="@string/title_activity_shake_page"
     android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" 
     android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme"
     android:parentActivityName="shake.shake.MainPage">
   </activity>

   <meta-data 
    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" 
    android:value="shake.shake.MainPage" />
```